# Why does cargo in a boat make the boat sink lower into the water?

Tags: free-body-diagram, buoyancy, fluid-statics

As you put more cargo into a boat it sits lower in the water, why does this happen? Is it just because the boat is heavier? Or because of more water being displaced?

Comment: What is your suggestion as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

In order to produce enough buoyancy to float, the amount of displaced water must have a weight equal to the weight of the boat. As more weight is added to the boat, it will lower further into the water thereby displacing more water. This is all known as Archimedes' Principle.

Answer (score -1):

A floating boat doesn't sink because its weight $W$ is balanced by the buoyancy $F_B$ provided by water. By Archimedes' principle, $F_B$ is equal to the weight of the fluid displaced. We can thus make the reasonable assumption that $F_B \propto h$ where $h$ is the depth reached by the boat. It is then clear that $W \propto h$, such that the heavier the boat, the lower it sits in the water.